# Adding comments to messages on message board in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple message board page that works like Facebook. User posts a message and users can comment on this message. Each message posts on the page and under each message there is a place to submit comments for that message. In my database there are tables for users, messages, and comments.

My question is: How do I know which specific message I am commenting on in order to properly pass this into the MySQL database with the corresponding message_id?

```
$comm = "INSERT INTO comments(user_id, message_id, comment, created_at, updated_at)
                    SELECT '{$_SESSION['id']}', '{$_SESSION['messages.id']}', '{$_SESSION['comment']}', NOW(), NOW()
                    FROM messages";
```

EDIT:

```
$query = "SELECT users.first_name AS first_name, users.last_name AS last_name, messages.id AS mess_id,
                    messages.message AS message, DATE_FORMAT(messages.created_at, '%M %e %Y') AS time
            FROM users
            LEFT JOIN messages
            ON  users.id = messages.user_id
            ORDER BY time DESC";

            $results = fetch($query);
            foreach ($results as $row) { 
                $_SESSION['messages.id'] = $row['mess_id'];
                echo 
                    "<div class='post'>". 
                    $row['first_name']. " ". $row['last_name']. " - ". $row['time']. "<br>".
                        "<p class='mess_content'>". $row['message']. "</p>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class='posted_comm'>";
                        $query = "SELECT users.first_name AS first_name, users.last_name AS last_name, 
                                    comments.message_id, DATE_FORMAT(comments.created_at, '%M %e %Y') AS time, comments.comment AS comment
                                FROM users
                                LEFT JOIN comments
                                ON  users.id = comments.user_id
                                WHERE comments.message_id = '{$_SESSION['messages.id']}'
                                ORDER BY time ASC";
                        $results1 = fetch($query);
                        foreach ($results1 as $value) {
                            echo
                            "<div class='comments'>". 
                                $value['first_name']. " ". $value['last_name']. " - ". $value['time']. "<br>".
                                "<p class='comm_content'>". $value['comment']. "</p>
                            </div><br>";
                        }
                echo "<div class='write_comm'>
                        <form method='post' action='mess_comm.php'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='action' value='post_comm'>
                            Post a comment:<input type='text' name='comm' class='comm'>
                            <input type='submit' value='Post a comment' class='comm_sub'>
                        </form>
                    </div>";
```

Comment: everything should be linked by IDs. Can you provide more details on your design?

Comment: add a hidden field with the post id to your comment form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extend your form to include the message id as a hidden field:

```
 echo "<div class='write_comm'>
                    <form method='post' action='mess_comm.php'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='post_comm'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='message_id' value='{$row['mess_id']}'>
                        Post a comment:<input type='text' name='comm' class='comm'>
                        <input type='submit' value='Post a comment' class='comm_sub'>
                    </form>
                </div>";
```

Then use the id in your query:

```
$comm = "INSERT INTO comments(user_id, message_id, comment, created_at, updated_at)
                VALUES ('{$_SESSION['id']}', '{$_POST['message_id']}', '{$_POST['comm']}', NOW(), NOW())";
```

Note: I corrected errors in your INSERT query. And you should look into prepared statements, right now your code is open for SQL injections.